# Not copying library, it's a directory

Tags: java, netbeans, directory

I get the "Not copying library, it's a directory" error when I build the jar in NetBeans. The problem is, that the directory it is referring to, is indeed no library and only contains a couple of properties and XML files. How do I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide the exact error?

Comment: Well it's quite a lot: http://pastebin.com/i47Y36rJ